# No Persistence provider for EntityManager in prod more

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.5, persistence.xml

I've been making an app using Play Framework 2.5 and I had no problems while running it in dev mode with run command, but once I try to switch to prod mode I am having this exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named defaultPersistenceUnit
```

my persistence.xml is in conf/META-INF/ folder

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>

    <class>models.entities.Artifact</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="testPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>models.entities.Artifact</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"
            value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Please give me at least some clues to where the problem might be